# What's the proper usage of cmp argument in built-in sorted function? [python 2.7]

Tags: python, sorting

I know there are three additional argument in sorted(): cmp, key, reverse

I know well how to use key and reverse. Key can fast sort a list which its content item have multiple subitems, and reverse simply reverse the result. for example:

```
>>> L1 = [('mama','1'),('papa','2'),('son','0')]
>>> L1 = sorted(L1, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
>>> L1
[('papa', '2'), ('mama', '1'), ('son', '0')]
```

But so far I didn't figure out how to use cmp properly, though read through the official document. Can anyone offer a nice use case for cmp argument in sorted()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmp` parameter accepts a function as argument which takes two arguments. The function is expected to return whether the first item is greater than, lesser than or equal to the second item.

But using that will be highly inefficient, as it has to be called for every comparison.

Quoting from [Python - Sorting wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_the_cmp_Parameter),

> Many constructs given in this HOWTO assume Python 2.4 or later. Before that, there was no `sorted()` builtin and `list.sort()` took no keyword arguments. Instead, all of the Py2.x versions supported a `cmp` parameter to handle user specified comparison functions.
>
> In Py3.0, the `cmp` parameter was removed entirely (as part of a larger effort to simplify and unify the language, eliminating the conflict between rich comparisons and the `__cmp__` methods).
>
> In Py2.x, sort allowed an optional function which can be called for doing the comparisons. That function should take two arguments to be compared and then return a negative value for less-than, return zero if they are equal, or return a positive value for greater-than. For example, we can do:
>
> ```
> >>> def numeric_compare(x, y):
>         return x - y
> >>> sorted([5, 2, 4, 1, 3], cmp=numeric_compare)
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> ```

**Note:** In Python 2.7, we have a function called [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) which can be used to convert a `cmp` function to a `key` function.

Comment: So this cmp function is kind of self-defined rule. which determines which element is huger. I got it. But how should I acquire this self defined rule function in python 3?

Comment: What do you mean by `acquire this self defined rule function`?

Comment: I mean cmp in sorted() can allow me to define a rule. In python 3.x it was removed from sorted(), what should I do if I want to achieve the same effect of cmp in sorted() of python 2.7 when I only have python 3.x in hand?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

> `cmp` specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (iterable elements) which should return a negative, zero or positive number depending on whether the first argument is considered smaller than, equal to, or larger than the second argument

When you sort a set of elements, you compare them against each other (this depends on the sorting algorithm) to try to figure out in what order they will be sorted. Here is where `cmp` comes to action.

Answer (score 1):

`cmp` was the original parameter used to provide a custom sort order, and was the *only* parameter until `key` was introduced in Python 2.4. `key` has always been recommended over `cmp` as more efficient (even prior to Python 2.4, the [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate) idiom was encouraged; the `key` parameter was introduced to simplify its implementation), and in Python 3 support for `cmp` was removed altogether.

As such, there is no separate use case for `cmp`; it just co-existed with `key` for a while before going away.